# Fastest way to fetch huge amount of data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I have more than 50,000 records in the database which I have to deal with in my application (and the number is increasing by 2000/day as a minimum).

The way I am currently using is: Linq to entities with a stored procedure in the database which is returning a collection of an object so that I can deal with it.

But I noticed that it is a slow, what is the most efficient way to get such a number of records from the database?

Sample of my code:

```
   items = (from f in db.spItems().OrderByDescending(f => f.date)
                  group f by f.ID into g
                  select g.FirstOrDefault()).Take(9).ToList();
                  join ar in db.anothertable on f.ID equals ar.ID
                  join t in db.thirdtable on ar.tid equals t.ID
```

spItems is a stored procedure which gets the results but sometimes i have to do multiple joins on it

Comment: It depends on how you are using the data.  Do you need all the data?  Or are you displaying only part of the data?  A bit more context please.

Comment: MultiThreading won't work here, since the other threads will block once one of them gets access to the DB.

Comment: as mnetioned below, i am only getting around 20 records but will multiple joins, i will put a sample of my code

Comment: @AliIssa: I'm not familiar with Linq-To-Sql but why do you use the `ToList()` in the query?

Answer (score 5):

I would first try to optimze your query. Is it slow  in SSMS? Do you use proper indices? Do you need all columns. Most important: do you need all 50000 rows to be displayed?

50000 records are not many records, but it's unusual to show all in a web application since that means you have to generate the HTML for all records and display it in the client's browser(maybe even using `ViewState`). So i would suggest to use database paging(f.e. via [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function) to partition your resultset and query only the data you want to show(f.e. 100 rows per page in a `GridView`).

[Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-vb)

Comment: i am only getting around 20 records but will multiple joins, i will put a sample of my code

Answer (score 5):

Please consider following steps. For this kind of issue we need to work at more than one layer.

**1.Use Standard way using ADO.net to fetch result**. Because  LINQ to SQL is ultimately an ORM (additional layer) so obviously it will lower the performance  which is noticeable  in just like you case. [**see here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70169/LINQ-to-SQL-Performance-Considerations)

**2. Please review again your table design** if you have not missed any thing like adding index,selected wrong datatype etc.

**3. Improve Stored Procedure performance** : [see here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/increase-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance-with-these-tips/)

**4. Divide Your Data.**:  Moved your old data other table if it is read only(or no longer going to be used) as you are telling that minimum new 2000 rows is added daily. So your table size will be decreasing significantly. **Please decide this decision very carefully.**

Answer (score 0):

Consider this article as a valuable additions to the previous answers: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2010/06/09/ado-net-entity-framework-4-0-loading-data-in-4-ways.aspx